# To paste the text from SAP into excel

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I am still new to SAP and VBA Excel.

I want to copy the text from sap to the Excel. As it the code run, it shows an empty cell.

I also want to do for loop to read each row of the purchase order.

Please point out the mistake, i made in this code.

```
Sub g142()

Worksheets("RCEP").Activate

Dim SapGuiAuto
Dim SetApp
Dim Connection
Dim Session

Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set SetApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set Connection = SetApp.Children(0)
Set Session = Connection.Children(0)

Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "va03"
Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-VBELN").Text = "" 'To delete info inside the order
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRV45S-BSTNK").Text = Cells(2, 1).Value 'Where I put purchase order number
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRV45S-BSTNK").SetFocus
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRV45S-BSTNK").caretPosition = 10
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/btnBT_SUCH").press
Session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_HEADER:SAPMV45A:4021/btnBT_HEAD").press 'Display Header Details
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\08").Select
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\08/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4152/subSUBSCREEN_TEXT:SAPLV70T:2100/cntlSPLITTER_CONTAINER/shellcont/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").selectItem "ZAV1", "Column1"
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\08/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4152/subSUBSCREEN_TEXT:SAPLV70T:2100/cntlSPLITTER_CONTAINER/shellcont/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").ensureVisibleHorizontalItem "ZAV1", "Column1" 'To scroll down
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\08/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4152/subSUBSCREEN_TEXT:SAPLV70T:2100/cntlSPLITTER_CONTAINER/shellcont/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").topNode = "ZAEH"
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\08/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4152/subSUBSCREEN_TEXT:SAPLV70T:2100/cntlSPLITTER_CONTAINER/shellcont/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").doubleClickItem "ZAV1", "Column1" 'Click to open G14
Cells(2, 19).Value = Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\08/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4152/subSUBSCREEN_TEXT:SAPLV70T:2100/cntlSPLITTER_CONTAINER/shellcont/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").Text'The text i want to copy
Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[12]").press 'To go back
Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[12]").press 'to go back

    
End Sub
```

I've tried various method from youtube and from this forum. Maybe, i did not understand what i tried to do to cause this code not working on my side.

Comment: I think you have to tell in detail what you mean with _not working on my side_ because code is working for me. Do you get any error message? Is Cells(2, 19) just empty?

Comment: I did not get error message and correct Cells(2, 19) shows empty cell which supposedly to copy the text in the container

Comment: As said, the line `Cells(2, 19).Value = Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\08/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4152/subSUBSCREEN_TEXT:SAPLV70T:2100/cntlSPLITTER_CONTAINER/shellcont/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").Text` is working for me and I get the text if there is any in SAP. If you want to copy the text from Excel into SAP you have to change the line. As it is written now it will copy the text from SAP into Excel.

Comment: You are right, it does pasted to the Excel. I don't know why I did not notice the text on the first place. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

as Storax mentioned. The code that I use is correct. Therefore, I also asked for looping each row to let SAP read the PO number then pasted into the Excel. Here is the code:

*'The only error I went through that I could not exit the loop and will end up showing Run-time error '619': The control could not be found by ID*
'*The error want to say there is no PO number to copy*

UPDATE: The line of code work now! below is the code if anyone want to use it

```
    Sub ToGetTXTfromG14()

Worksheets("RCEP").Activate

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim SapGuiAuto
Dim SetApp
Dim Connection
Dim Session

Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set SetApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set Connection = SetApp.Children(0)
Set Session = Connection.Children(0)

Dim rng As Range
Dim actrng As Range
Dim i As Long

Set actrng = Range("A1")
Set rng = Sheets("RCEP").Range("A2")
Rowmax = Sheets("RCEP").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp).Row

    
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/n"
    Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "va03"
    Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    
For i = 1 To Rowmax
   
    If IsEmpty(actrng.Offset(i, 0).Value) Or actrng.Offset(i, 0).Value = "" Then
        Exit For 
    End If
    
   
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-VBELN").Text = "" 'To delete info inside the order
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRV45S-BSTNK").Text = actrng.Offset(i, 0).Value  'Where I put purchase order number
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRV45S-BSTNK").SetFocus
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRV45S-BSTNK").caretPosition = 10
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/btnBT_SUCH").press
    Session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_HEADER:SAPMV45A:4021/btnBT_HEAD").press 'Display Header Details
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\08").Select
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\08/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4152/subSUBSCREEN_TEXT:SAPLV70T:2100/cntlSPLITTER_CONTAINER/shellcont/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").selectItem "ZAV1", "Column1"
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\08/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4152/subSUBSCREEN_TEXT:SAPLV70T:2100/cntlSPLITTER_CONTAINER/shellcont/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").ensureVisibleHorizontalItem "ZAV1", "Column1" 'To scroll down
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\08/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4152/subSUBSCREEN_TEXT:SAPLV70T:2100/cntlSPLITTER_CONTAINER/shellcont/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").topNode = "ZAEH"
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\08/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4152/subSUBSCREEN_TEXT:SAPLV70T:2100/cntlSPLITTER_CONTAINER/shellcont/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").doubleClickItem "ZAV1", "Column1" 'Click to open G14
    actrng.Offset(i, 18).Value = Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\08/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4152/subSUBSCREEN_TEXT:SAPLV70T:2100/cntlSPLITTER_CONTAINER/shellcont/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").Text  '= actrng.Offset(i, 19).Value 'The text i want to copy Cells(2, 19).Value =
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[12]").press 'To go back
   
Next i

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    
End Sub
```